# MT4J on Android?

Tags: java, android, multi-touch, mt4j

A quick Google search hasn't yielded any answers to this:

Are there any factors that would prevent me from developing on Android using `MT4J`?

Comment: I don't know if it's compatible. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm tryna ee if there is a direct way to port MT4J apps written for the desktop to Android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MT4j now has an Android port :)

You can get it here:
http://code.google.com/p/mt4j/downloads/

Answer (score 1):

I am currently looking into porting MT4j to the Android platform and identifying what would have to be modified. MT4j in its current form is targeted at desktop only.
e.g.:
- replace/remove all dependencies on java awt/swing
- abstract OpenGL calls to allow OpenGL ES backend
- remove/replace opengl calls unsupported by OpenGL ES
- remove/replace dependencies on Java libraries/classes not available on Android

The goal would be to be able to use your existing MT4j scenes without changes on the MT4j Android port. Im hoping to get to this soon, help is appreciated =)

Comment: Thanks for the response! Let me know how it goes - I have put this one on the backburner.